# How to generate 5-character strings combinations (2 different digits, two equal letters and 1 letter) without duplication

Tags: python, math, combinatorics

I already published [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224466/how-to-generate-5-character-strings-combinations-1-digit-two-equal-letters-and) but this is a **DIFFERENT** question.
I am trying to generate combinations of a 5-character strings consisting of **three** letters (exactly two are equal and another different letter) and two **different** digits but I got duplication when I tried to do so.

Example for **CORRECT** combinations:

```
82ccb  
b8cc7  
7c6dc
```

Example for **INCORRECT** combinations:

```
22ddc  -> incorrect because the digits are equal and should be different
46ddd  -> incorrect because there are more than 2 equal letters
2t4cd  -> No 2 equal letters + 2 equal different letters
```

This is the code I am using:

```
LETTERS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
DIGITS = '2456789'

def aab12(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    """Generate the distinct 5-character strings consisting of three
    letters (two are equal and a repeated letter) and two digits (each one is different from the other).

    """
    letterdxs = set(range(5))
    combs = []
    for (d1, d2), (i, j), (l1, l2) in product(
            permutations(digits, 2),       # 2 digits (a repeated).
            combinations(range(5), 2),     # Positions for the 1st and 2nd digits.
            permutations(letters, 2)):     # 2 letters (a repeated).

        x, y, z = letterdxs.difference((i, j))
        s = set((x, y, z))
        # Choosing 2 positions for the repeated letters
        c1 = combinations((x, y, z), 2) 
        for c in c1:
            result = []
            result[i:i] = d1,
            result[j:j] = d2,
            result[c[0]:c[0]] = l1,
            result[c[1]:c[1]] = l1,
            # Choosing position for the last letter. This is position that was left
            letter_indx = (s.difference(c)).pop()
            result[letter_indx:letter_indx] = l2,
            combs.append(''.join(result))
    # Should be 478,800
    print(len(combs))
    return combs

def is_contain_dup(combos):
    s = set(combos)
    if len(s) != len(combos):
       print('found duplicates !')

is_contain_dup(aab12())
```

I have duplication although the length is ok.
This function is based on this math:
[image]

- Choosing 2 places for the different digits
- Choosing 2 places for the repeated letter
- Choosing different letter from the last letter

I am not sure what is causing the duplication but this is probably something with the choosing of the two equal letters + different letter.

Comment: Sorry, out of time to rework my answer. Tomorrow perhaps.

Comment: Are `82ccb` and `82cbc` the same or different?

Comment: They are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is pure brute force, naive method with 4 nested loops:

```
LETTERS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
DIGITS = '2456789'
from itertools import permutations

def aab12_1(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    st=[]
    for fc in letters:
        for sc in letters:
            if sc==fc: continue
            for n1 in digits:
                for n2 in digits:
                    if n1==n2: continue 
                    st.append(''.join((fc,fc,sc,n1,n2)))
    di={e:[''.join(t) for t in permutations(e)] for e in st}    
    return {s for sl in di.values() for s in sl}    

>>> r=aab12_1()
>>> len(r)
478800
```

This has `O(n**4)` complexity; ie, *really bad* for longer strings. However, the example strings are not so long and this is a doable approach for shorter strings.

You can cut the complexity a bit by sorting the generated base strings to cut the duplicate calls to `permutations`:

```
def aab12_2(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    st=set()
    for fc in letters:
        for sc in letters:
            if sc==fc: continue
            for n1 in digits:
                for n2 in digits:
                    if n1==n2: continue 
                    st.add(''.join(sorted((fc,fc,sc,n1,n2))))

    di={e:[''.join(t) for t in permutations(e)] for e in st}    
    return {s for sl in di.values() for s in sl}
```

That can be streamlined a bit further to:

```
from itertools import permutations, product, combinations

def aab12_3(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    let_combo=[x+y for x,y in product([e+e for e in letters],letters) if x[0]!=y]   
    n_combos={a+b for a,b in combinations(digits,2)}
    di={e:[''.join(t) for t in permutations(e)] for e in (x+y for x,y in product(let_combo, n_combos))} 
    return {s for sl in di.values() for s in sl}
```

That still has an implied `O(n**3)` with 3 `products()` which is the equivalent of a nested loop for each. Each `O` is faster however and the overall time here is now about 350 ms.

So, let's benchmark. Here are the 3 functions from above, Ajax1234's recursive function, and Rory Daulton's itertools function:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations, product

def aab12_1(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    st=[]
    for fc in letters:
        for sc in letters:
            if sc==fc: continue
            for n1 in digits:
                for n2 in digits:
                    if n1==n2: continue 
                    st.append(''.join((fc,fc,sc,n1,n2)))
    di={e:[''.join(t) for t in permutations(e)] for e in st}    
    return {s for sl in di.values() for s in sl}    

def aab12_2(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    st=set()
    for fc in letters:
        for sc in letters:
            if sc==fc: continue
            for n1 in digits:
                for n2 in digits:
                    if n1==n2: continue 
                    st.add(''.join(sorted((fc,fc,sc,n1,n2))))
    di={e:[''.join(t) for t in permutations(e)] for e in st}    
    return {s for sl in di.values() for s in sl}    


def aab12_3(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    let_combo=[x+y for x,y in product([e+e for e in letters],letters) if x[0]!=y]   
    n_combos={a+b for a,b in combinations(digits,2)}
    di={e:[''.join(t) for t in permutations(e)] for e in (x+y for x,y in product(let_combo, n_combos))} 
    return {s for sl in di.values() for s in sl} 

def aab12_4():
# Ajax1234 recursive approach
    def validate(val, queue, counter):
        if not queue:
            return True
        if val.isdigit():
            return sum(i.isdigit() for i in queue) < 2 and val not in queue
        _sum = sum(i.isalpha() for i in counter)
        return _sum < 3 and counter.get(val, 0) < 2

    def is_valid(_input):
        d = Counter(_input)
        return sum(i.isdigit() for i in d) == 2 and sum(i.isalpha() for i in d) == 2

    def combinations(d, current = []):
        if len(current) == 5:
            yield ''.join(current)
        else:
            for i in d:
                if validate(i, current, Counter(current)):
                    yield from combinations(d, current+[i])

    return [i for i in combinations(DIGITS+LETTERS) if is_valid(i)]


def aab12_5(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    """ Rory Daulton
    Generate the distinct 5-character strings consisting of three
    letters (two are equal and a repeated letter) and two digits (each
    one is different from the other).
    """
    indices = range(5)  # indices for the generated 5-char strings
    combs = []
    for (letterdbl, lettersngl), (digit1, digit2), (indx1, indx2, indx3) in (
            product(permutations(letters, 2),
            combinations(digits, 2),
            permutations(indices, 3))):
        charlist = [letterdbl] * 5
        charlist[indx1] = lettersngl
        charlist[indx2] = digit1
        charlist[indx3] = digit2
        combs.append(''.join(charlist))
    return combs    

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit
    funcs=(aab12_1,aab12_2,aab12_3,aab12_4,aab12_5)
    di={f.__name__:len(set(f())) for f in funcs}
    print(di)
    for f in funcs:
        print("   {:^10s}{:.4f} secs".format(f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f()", setup="from __main__ import f", number=1)))
```

Prints:

```
{'aab12_1': 478800, 'aab12_2': 478800, 'aab12_3': 478800, 'aab12_4': 478800, 'aab12_5': 478800}
   aab12_1  0.6230 secs
   aab12_2  0.3433 secs
   aab12_3  0.3292 secs
   aab12_4  50.4786 secs
   aab12_5  0.2094 secs
```

The fastest here is Rory Daulton's itertools function. Nicely done!

Comment: I didn't check it yet but when you wrote you used a brute force I thought it will be slower.

Comment: Works very fast, nice. When I published the question I was also interesting what was the problem is my code, so I hope that if someone sees it he can tell me.

Comment: Lol, I liked you made a contest. I can upload it to the code golf forums and see if someone can do it better ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a recursive function:

```
from collections import Counter
LETTERS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
DIGITS = '2456789'
def validate(val, queue, counter):
  if not queue:
    return True
  if val.isdigit():
    return sum(i.isdigit() for i in queue) < 2 and val not in queue
  _sum = sum(i.isalpha() for i in counter)
  return _sum < 3 and counter.get(val, 0) < 2

def is_valid(_input):
  d = Counter(_input)
  return sum(i.isdigit() for i in d) == 2 and sum(i.isalpha() for i in d) == 2

def combinations(d, current = []):
  if len(current) == 5:
    yield ''.join(current)
  else:
    for i in d:
      if validate(i, current, Counter(current)):
        yield from combinations(d, current+[i])

_r = [i for i in combinations(DIGITS+LETTERS) if is_valid(i)]
print(len(_r))
```

Output:

```
478800
```

Comment: You corrected the output but now it is *really slow.*

Answer (score 2):

Here is one answer that uses multiple functions in `itertools`. My strategy is stated in the comments. As much looping as possible is done in the `itertools` functions, to maximize speed. This returns the desired 478,800 strings, which are all distinct.

Running `%timeit` on `aab12()` on my system gives the time result

```
391 ms ± 2.34 ms per loop
```

.

```
"""
Strategy: Generate a permutation of 2 distinct characters, a
combination of 2 distinct digits, and a permutation of 3 distinct
indices in range(5). Then build a 5-char string of the first character
(which will be the repeated one), use the first two indices to place
the digits and the last index to place the non-repeated character.
This yields a total of (20*19) * (7/1*6/2) * (5*4*3) = 478,800
items.
"""
from itertools import combinations, permutations, product

LETTERS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
DIGITS = '2456789'

def aab12(letters=LETTERS, digits=DIGITS):
    """Generate the distinct 5-character strings consisting of three
    letters (two are equal and a repeated letter) and two digits (each
    one is different from the other).
    """
    indices = range(5)  # indices for the generated 5-char strings
    combs = []
    for (letterdbl, lettersngl), (digit1, digit2), (indx1, indx2, indx3) in (
            product(permutations(letters, 2),
                    combinations(digits, 2),
                    permutations(indices, 3))):
        charlist = [letterdbl] * 5
        charlist[indx1] = digit1
        charlist[indx2] = digit2
        charlist[indx3] = lettersngl
        combs.append(''.join(charlist))
    return combs
```

The first fifteen strings in the list are

```
['24cbb',
 '24bcb',
 '24bbc',
 '2c4bb',
 '2b4cb',
 '2b4bc',
 '2cb4b',
 '2bc4b',
 '2bb4c',
 '2cbb4',
 '2bcb4',
 '2bbc4',
 '42cbb',
 '42bcb',
 '42bbc']
```

Comment: Mike drop. Nice

Comment: Really nice solution and elegant ! I especially liked that you created the the double letter 5 times and the rest of the combinations made it two. I also liked that you gave better names for the variables. Great :)

Comment: @E235: Thanks. That seemed the simplest way to get 2 copies of that letter and still not need to check for duplicate strings.